# React JS Props not updating

Tags: reactjs, react-props, react-functional-component

In the code below when I change the state of pendingCount the first key prop changes but the one inside the **< Pending/>** does not. Why is that?

```
         <div>
            <motion.p
                key={pendingCount}
                whileHover={{textDecoration:"underline"}}
                style={{cursor:"pointer"}}
                onClick={ ()=>{ render(<Pending key={pendingCount} data={AllPendingsData}/>) } }
                className="position-relative d-inline-block pe-3"
            >
                Pending Requests
                <span className="badge rounded-pill bg-dark ms-2">
                    {pendingCount}
                </span>
            </motion.p>
        </div>
```

There is one more thing that I want to add that is that what I wanted to do was to re-render the **< Pending/>** when its props changes. Changing the key prop was one of the suggested way that I found on the internet for this but it is not working for me. So is there any better or preferred way to do for a functional component?

Comment: You can use `useState` to set value whether it's clicked or not, then use `useEffect` and add that state value as a dependency if you are trying to re-render the component depending on clicked value.

Comment: What is that `onClick` callback doing? This isn't a normal way to render JSX in React. What is that `render` function, can you share a more complete and comprehensive code example?

Comment: Actually the code in the question belongs to a sidebar. I am storing the component that is being rendered in body in a state and the render method changes that state. So when the onClick is triggered it will change the state. I just want to re-render or update the Pending component.
 (Note: I do not want to use react-router for this)

Comment: React state updates are asynchronous, so it's very easy to have synchronicity issues. It's also anti-pattern to store React components in component state, just store the intrinsic data and render the JSX from that. Is the `AllPendingsData` ultimately what you want to store and render? Can you provide a more complete and comprehensive code example for what you are trying to do?

Comment: So I changed the code and instead of storing component in a state, now I am using a switch statement and by render method I store an object which I use in switch statement to render different component. Everything works but the change in props still don't cause any re-render in the children component to which it was passed.

Comment: Which prop(s) are you updating? Keep in mind that in React `key` and `ref` are special and ***not*** passed on to children components as props. https://reactjs.org/warnings/special-props.html

Comment: I am updating data prop but the change in data prop on parent side does not gets reflected in the children which I think is due to the fact that props are immutable. I found some solution on the net in which if I change the special props like key, the entire component will get re-rendered which is not same in my case.

Comment: Yeah, `props` (and `state`) are to be treated as immutable objects. Can you update your question to include a more complete and comprehensive component code example for what you are trying to update in the parent and pass to a child component?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the onClick just as Drew Reese mentioned.
Props are causing updates but only when user clicks the element.
So instead of passing the data as prop I used useContext hook which solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Do you use props or state?

for test you try with state

Comment: This isn't an answer, btw, questions asking for clarification should be made a comments.

Comment: sorry but I don't get it. I am using both state and props just passing down that state as prop to the child component.